# If the conductor floats in a horizontal homogeneous magnetic field, what is the current?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, experimental-physics, magnetostatics

If the conductor floats in a horizontal homogeneous magnetic field, its magnetic flux density is 0.75 T and one meter of conductor weighs 2.5 g. How to calculate current. So when the length or mass is not directly known?

Is it IlB=m/l *g or IB=m/l*g, i.e. what do you do with 2.5 g per meter?

Thanks to everyone who helps!

Comment: English is not my first language so please forgive me if did any mistakes

Comment: Hint: Suppose, the conductor is carrying some current $I$ in the horizontal direction, and the magnetic field is perpendicular to it (but also horizontal). What is the magnitude and direction of the force on it? Can this magnetic force oppose the gravitational attraction, so that the conductor will levitate?

Comment: Can you use some formulas please and thanks for helping. I have an upcoming example and this was hard for everyone in my class.

Comment: I found these notes on magnetic force and some related solved examples https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Book%3A_University_Physics_(OpenStax)/Book%3A_University_Physics_II_-_Thermodynamics_Electricity_and_Magnetism_(OpenStax)/11%3A_Magnetic_Forces_and_Fields/11.05%3A_Magnetic_Force_on_a_Current-Carrying_Conductor

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please note that this site is not for homework-like-questions. You will have to show some effort, and describe what is confusing you to get an answer. You added some formulas, how do you think they are obtained? To begin with, what are the forces on the conductor?

Comment: `So when the length or mass is not directly known?` Suppose the conductor is rod shaped (this simplification is not necessary), and has length $l$. Then, the mass of the conductor is known, since you know the mass per unit length. Once you figure out what are the forces on the conductor, and write an equation so that the total force on the conductor is zero (so that it will levitate), you will find that the length $l$ cancels out (which is why, the exact length is not necessary to solve the problem).

Comment: are the forces affecting the conductor :weight i.e. G=mg and magnetic force i.e. F_m=IlB? I just don't understand how that length is supposed to br canceled out. I know that F_m=G so IlB=mg but the length is still a problem

Comment: I just find dealing with the length challeging please can you just tell  me how to deal with it? Oh and thanks for your time and effort

Comment: You know $m/l$, which is 2.5 g/meter. The exact value of $m$ or $l$ is not necessary, if you equate $F_m = \text{Weight}$

Comment: Okei I tried to do as you said so I got IlB=mg and the current is I=(mg)/B so (0,0025kg*9,81 m/s^2)/(0,75T)=0,0327A which is also about 33mA

Comment: But my teacher said it's not like that to one of my friends

Comment: Is this correct in your opinion?

Comment: In your previous comment (where you equated the upwards magnetic force with downward gravity) you found the value of the current (about 32.7 mA) necessary to levitate the wire. You have solved the problem! Did your teacher say this is wrong?

Comment: Thank you so much!